# C++ Debug Assert Error / Crash (While Loop)

Tags: c++, debugging

I'm debugging a very old application (Visual C++ 6) due to a crash. I have isolated the crash into a while loop. This app reads a bunch of strings from a database and outputs them into a file for processing.

This while loop appears to be looping through all strings retrieved from the DB and wrapping them in a delimiter/end character. However, the while loop will randomly crash.

I have a particular set of data containing around **2000 strings**, and at some point, during processing, the loop will crash (or give a debug assertion error in debug mode).

What's strange is that this loop does not stop in the same location each time (bad string was my first thought), nor is this a common occurrence. This app has processed hundreds of thousands of rows over the years, and yet it chokes on this particular data set somewhat randomly.

I added some logging code initially (which I've stripped out, and it appears that the crash is occurring on the actual execution/evaluation of the `WHILE` line.

Is there anything, in particular, I should look for? I was thinking perhaps this is an index out of bounds error, but I would think it would happen consistently in the same spot with the same data set if that were the case. Does anyone see anything with this code I should double-check, or can offer any advice on how to better troubleshoot this?

```
//Definitions
CStringList          m_stlMessageList;
CStringList          m_stlMessageIDList;    


//Populating list
rec.Open(CRecordset::forwardOnly, strSQL);
while (!rec.IsEOF())
{
    rec.GetFieldValue("string_id", strMessageID);
    strMessageID.TrimRight();
    rec.GetFieldValue("string_text", strMessage);
    strMessage.TrimRight();
    rec.GetFieldValue("string_destination", strDestination);
    strDestination.TrimRight();
    rec.GetFieldValue("string_ip", strIP);
    strIP.TrimRight();

    //Add to the Lists...
    m_stlMessageIDList.AddTail(strMessageID);
    m_stlMessageList.AddTail(strMessage);

    rec.MoveNext();
}



//Code thats crashing.
CString strSegment, strTemp, strTmp;
BOOL    bFirst = TRUE;
POSITION POS = m_stlMessageList.GetHeadPosition();
while (POS)
{

                strSegment     = m_stlMessageList.GetNext(POS);                                                  
                strTemp        = strSegment.Left(4);
    
                            
                strSegment.Format(strSegment + "%c", 13);
                if (POS)
                {
                                strTmp = m_stlMessageList.GetPrev(POS);
                                m_stlMessageList.SetAt(POS, strSegment);
                                strTmp = m_stlMessageList.GetNext(POS);
                }
                else
                {
                                m_stlMessageList.RemoveTail();
                                m_stlMessageList.AddTail(strSegment);
                }                                                              

}
```

Comment: What exactly is the assertion text that you see? Furthermore, what is the type of `m_stlMessageList`? Also, I notice that `POS` is not updated inside the loop - have you omitted that code?

Comment: Assuming `m_stlMessageList` is a `CList` and that there is some code that sets `POS` before the `if`, if `POS` is `NULL`, then [`RemoveTail()` will assert](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9y10e52d\(v=vs.80\).aspx#Anchor_1).

Comment: The POS is being loaded prior to the while loop by the Position POS = m_stlMessageList.GetHeadPosition(). The type of m_stlMessageList is a CStringList. The only error I see for assertion is the pop-up that says "Debug Assertion Failed" and gives me a line number in the debug version. I added logging code (which I omitted above) to narrow down that it appears the crash is occuring on the while(POS) line. In release mode I get the error "Unhandled exception in  MSVCRT.DLL, Access Violation".